# Java function interface for Supplier<T> failed to compile non-lambda

Tags: java, function, lambda, interface, supplier

I've got this:

```
import java.util.function.*;
public class FluentApi {
    public Integer myfunc(){
        return Integer.valueOf(1);
    }
    public void fSupplier(Supplier<Integer> si){
        System.out.println(si.get());
    }
    public void callFunc(){
        fSupplier(myfunc); // compilation failure
    }
}
```

It says: `myfunc cannot be resolved to a variableJava(33554515)`

If I change it to a lambda function then it compiles:

```
    public void callFunc(){
        fSupplier(()->Integer.valueOf(1));
    }
```

So what is the core difference here? How can I use a non-lambda implementation here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass `myfunc` as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Try this:

```java
public void callFunc() {
    fSupplier(this::myfunc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method have one parameter of type `Supplier<Integer>` so you have three choices to pass as argument to this method (the idea is to pass an instance of a class who implements the functional interface Supplier):

- A lambda expression

  ```
  public void callFunc() {
      fSupplier(()->Integer.valueOf(1));
  }
  ```
- A method reference

  ```
  public void callFunc() {
       fSupplier(this::myfunc);
   }
  ```
- An anonymous inner class

  ```
   public void callFunc(){
       fSupplier(new Supplier<Integer>() {

           @Override
           public Integer get() {
               return Integer.valueOf(1);
           }
       }); 
   }
  ```